# Merge field text alignment

Tags: for-loop, salesforce, docusignapi

In *DocuSign for Salesforce* I have several merge fields in my document. When I send the document to the signer the placement of the merge field data does not align with the text line. This an anchor tag document. The sender does not have the capability to go in and align all of the many fields.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The DocuSign for Salesforce app does not have the ability to edit merge fields so unfortunately I don't believe you can resolve this issue through Salesforce.  You should, however, be able to resolve if you have access to the template in question.  Just login to the DocuSign Console through the login button at www.docusign.com and edit the template and re-align the DocuSign tab in question.  If you don't have access to the Console/template then perhaps a team member can help?